# C# Game Setting message Takes away first character

Tags: c#

So If you set it to like

> abcdefg

it will come out like

> bcdefg

Here's changing the message

[image]

Here's the result

[image]

Here's the code

```
//Set Welcome msg
else if (Type == 6)
{
    if (Character.Network.Stall.isOpened) return;
    short length = Reader.Int16();
    Character.Network.Stall.WelcomeMsg = Reader.Text3();
    Character.Network.Stall.Send(Packet.StallWelcome(Character.Network.Stall.WelcomeMsg));
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of context. What is the `Character` class? What is "Game Setting"?

Comment: The images load fine for me.  You may need to post additional code in order for the truncation to be diagnosed properly.

Comment: Oh hey look it's Silkroad Online.  It's cool to see this kind of thing on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

char is 16 bits, are you sure you aren't reading the first char when you try to read the length?

Try reading the whole block as text:

```
else if (Type == 6)
{
    if (Character.Network.Stall.isOpened) return;
    Character.Network.Stall.WelcomeMsg = Reader.Text3();
    Character.Network.Stall.Send(Packet.StallWelcome(Character.Network.Stall.WelcomeMsg));
}
```